# Return value from deferred nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a caching function which loads invisible content into the DOM so that div sizes can be calculated correctly (including images). I am using jQuery's deferred object to run a function once the caching is complete.

The problem I am having is I can't work out how to return my **props** object once the caching function is complete. The `return props` at the bottom is obviously where I want to return my properties object, but it's returning undefined as the _obj function hasn't completed by the time the return is called.

My **complete** function near the bottom is correctly logging the props object (inc the **cacheHeight** var), but I can't work out how to return the props object from the deferred function. I'd like to do something like `return _obj(content).done(complete);`, but obviously that returns the deferred object, not the return from the complete function.

```
    cache : function(content) {

        // Vars
        var props;
        // Deferred switch
        var r = $.Deferred();

        /*
         * Cache object
         */
        var _obj = function(content) {
            cacheHeight = 0;
            cache = document.createElement("div");
            cache.style.visibility = "hidden";
            $(cache).css("position", "fixed"); // prevents parent's size being affected
            $(cache).append(content);
            $(contentWrapper).append(cache);
            children = $(cache).children();
            // Image loader
            var imgs = $(cache).find('img'),
                img_length = imgs.length,
                img_load_cntr = 0;
            if (img_length) { //if the $img_container contains new images.
                imgs.on('load', function() { //then we avoid the callback until images are loaded
                    img_load_cntr++;
                    if (img_load_cntr == img_length) {
                        remaining = children.length;
                        $.each(children, function(index, value) {
                            --remaining;
                            cacheHeight = cacheHeight + parseInt($(value).outerHeight(false));
                            if (remaining == 0) {
                                props = {
                                    height : cacheHeight
                                }
                                r.resolve();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            return r;
        };

        /*
         * Return cached object data
         */
        var complete = function () {
            console.log(props); // Correctly logs props object
        };

        // Resolve when finished
        _obj(content).done(complete);

        console.log(props); // Logs props as undefined (not good)
        // Return?!?!
        return props;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you passed in a function as a callback into the cache parameters to access the props variable. I'm wondering if you are returning props before it's set.

Answer (score 0):

When calling the resolve it can accept arguments, so you should call it like this:

```
r.resolve(args);
```

and then the done will automatically transfer it to your callback:

```
         /*
         * Return cached object data
         */
        var complete = function (args) {
            //use args as you see fit
            ready = true;
        };
```

For more details: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem here is that I can already receive the props object in the complete function, as I have set it globally. Since the complete function runs when the deferred call is ready, it always has the correct value, I just want to return the props object from the parent (cache) function

Comment: Instead, make the entire cache method deferred and resolve it when prop is ready

Comment: Jan - please read the question accurately, I have stated that it's returning undefined as the _obj function hasn't completed by the time the return is called. @Fatman - I'll still have the same issue returning the object as it is inside the nested function. I need to retrieve it to be used in other functions in the script, so my cache object will provide me with data (in this case, the elements height) to be used in an ajax content load.

Comment: Again, make the cache function deferred and return the value with result, the same as you do inside the function. so instead of returning prop, return a deferred object and in `complete` function do `def.resolve(prop)`